# Update Sitecore and SIP together?

Tags: sitecore, sip

I currently have the task of updating a Sitecore Instance 6.6 with SIP 3.2. The target is reaching Sitecore 7.0, so we can use Item Buckets.

The problem is when I update Sitecore to 7.0, it doesn't work with SIP 3.2, because assembly references doesn't match anymore and Sitecore 7.0 runs on .NET 4.5, where SIP 3.2 runs on .NET 3.5. So the Sitecore Backend does not work anymore and I cannot update the SIP.

If I update the SIP to 4.0 (which works with Sitecore 7.0) before updating the Sitecore Instance to 7.0, I get a similar problem.

Any idea what I can do to update both together? Or is there another way of achiving Sitecore 7.0 with SIP 4.0?

Comment: Would you be able to remove SIP, upgrade sitecore then reinstall SIP 4.0?

Comment: Not sure, how would I do that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it is installed via a Sitecore Package, so removing the Item, code files and config would achieve this

Comment: Is there no other way? I have doubts that I can identify all files and items, because the project got so complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend uninstalling SIP first. You can achieve this is via removing the code files and configs from the solution manually - you can try leaving the Sitecore Items there as they shouldn't cause issues.

It will be helpful to redownloading the SIP package, unzip to see the files and view which files and configs it contains, then remove those from your solution.

A simpler way if you have Sitecore Rocks is to create an Anti-package - https://www.sitecore.net/nl-be/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/trevor-campbell/posts/2013/02/28-days-of-sitecore-rocks-package-management-part-1.aspx

Once you have removed SIP, complete your upgrade of Sitecore and confirm your site serves correctly afterwards.

Then its a matter of installing the correct version of SIP for the version of Sitecore 7 you have upgraded to. This will mitigate the issue of assemblies being different versions.

I would recommend backing up your databases before the upgrade as best practice but to also retrieve any SIP Item you may later need.

Comment: What exactly do mean with "code files"? Layouts and sublayouts?

Comment: Aspx, Ascx, dlls etc. You'll see all these code files when you unzip the SIP package then you can go through and remove these